# Javascript: rowIndex() function gives zero-indexed value in IE, but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm trying to pull a `rowIndex` value from a table using the following line of code:

`var selected = document.getElementById("selected").rowIndex;`

However, I noticed that a certain value changes based on my browser type. On Chrome, the value of the first row in the `tbody` section is always `1`, whereas in IE, it starts at `0`. For my application, I need it to start at `0`.

My table structure looks like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>A32</td>
           <td>Book</td>
           <td>Small</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A34</td>
          <td>Car</td>
          <td>Large</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>T83</td>
          <td>Computer</td>
          <td>Medium</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**What can I do to fix this issue, and how did it happen in the first place?**

Comment: to me both starts with 0.

Comment: Chrome probably counts all rows, not just the ones in the body tag

Comment: check this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tr_rowindex2

Comment: Indeed chrome and FF counts the `thead` row as one row, IE might be the only browser that doesn't. Can you edit the table itself or add attribute to it or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as explained by Musa and Huangism in the comments above, was that Chrome counts all rows in a table, including header rows. To solve this problem, I made a script to detect a given browser type and include/not include offset-by-one for `rowIndex`.

```
function detectIE() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;


    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    if (msie > 0) {
        // IE 10 or older => return version number
        return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
    }

    var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    if (trident > 0) {
        // IE 11 => return version number
        var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
        return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
    }

    var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
    if (edge > 0) {
        // Edge (IE 12+) => return version number
        return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf('.', edge)), 10);
    }

    // other browser
    return false;
}

var offset = 0;
    if(detectIE())
        offset = 0;
    else
        offset = 1;

var selected = document.getElementById("selected").rowIndex - offset;
```

The above is handy if you need a fix, but keep in mind that user agent strings may change in the future.